# Degree of divergence of subdiagram

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, dimensional-analysis, effective-field-theory

The proof of the Appelquist-Carazzone theorem involves analyzing the behaviour of an internal subdiagram which is a fermion loop with $F$ incoming vector lines. The mass of the fermion is assumed much heavier than the physical, external momenta of the parent graph ($m \gg p_i$). In my mind, this subdiagram should behave like

$$
\mathcal{A} \sim \int d^4 \ell \prod_{i=1}^F \frac{1}{\displaystyle{\not}\ell -m - \sum_{j=1}^i k_j},
$$
where $k$ are the momenta of the bosons incoming to the subdiagram. The proof than states that, because $m$ is too large, the momenta may be rescaled away:

$$
\mathcal{A} \sim \int d^4 \ell \frac{1}{(\displaystyle{\not}\ell -m)^F},
$$
which is said to scale as

$$
m^{4-F}.
$$
Note that, in practice, the large mass regime is said to be taken into account with a limit $m \to \infty$ being taken.

My questions:

1. Why can we truly disregard the momenta $k$? Since these are not the actual external momenta, they could be loop momenta external to the subdiagram and be very big, could they not?
2. I also don't understand why the integral above behaves like $m^{4-F}$, although it seems obvious. That is, $\ell$ is able to grow to become as large as $m$, as it is being integrated over. Can you explain this behavior to me?

**Edit:** Check, for instance, page 28 of [this master thesis by S.A.W. de Wit](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.ru.nl/publish/pages/913395/master_thesis_stefan_de_wit.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwi4pPL9os3_AhXnJrkGHWGxAG84ChAWegQIChAB&usg=AOvVaw2LPNpHhOPO0RHMDi6UdUJl), or the original paper 'Infrared Singularities and Massive Fields'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. It seems that (at least part of) OP's question comes down how [renormalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization) works and why we truly can assign a finite value to a UV-divergent Feynman diagram. That is a very good question, which can be answered using the methods of Dyson or Wilson.
2. If we accept that the renormalized value of the fermion loop subdiagram is finite, it is easy to see from dimensional analysis that it is $$m^{4-F}(1+ {\cal O}(k/m)) $$
   up to a multiplicative dimensionless proportionality factor. The fermion loop subdiagram can be seen as effective coupling constants for (possible derivative) $F$-vertices of the boson field $A^a_{\mu}$.
3. OP asks about the loop momenta $k$ of the remaining part of the parent diagram, which could be UV-divergent. That can be dealt with using the Wilsonian effective action. The experimental scale is here assumed to be much smaller than the heavy fermion mass $m$.
4. In particular, if both the parent diagram and the fermionic loop subdiagram(s) are superficially convergent, then a UV-divergence in the remaining part of the parent diagram is an artifact of treating the fermionic loop(s) as [irrelevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Renormalization_group) effective coupling(s).

References:

1. S.A.W. de Wit, *Decoupling Heavy Fermions in the Scalar
   Sector,* [master thesis](https://www.ru.nl/highenergyphysics/theses/master-theses/), 2022; p.28-29.
2. T. Appelquist & J. Carazzone, *Infrared singularities and massive fields,* [Phys. Rev. D11 (1975) 2856](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevD.11.2856).

Comment: Let me see if I understand it correctly: (i) We basically assume the subdiagram is renormalized (or renormalizable) and, by dimensional analysis of the $F$-point function, conclude it has mass dimensions of $F-4$ and then that it behaves as $m^{F-4}$ because it is the relevant mass scale available? And (ii) the reason we don't worry about the size of the incoming (possibly virtual) momenta is that we are, in the end of the day, analysing a cutoff, wilsonian style, external loop integral?

Comment: Essentially yes.